# Java output formatting

Tags: java, format

I was wondering if Java has some sort of class to help on output formatting. I know in C++, in iomanip, there is a method call setw. I was wondering if Java has something similar to this.

Comment: What output are you trying to achieve? Is this a console program or a GUI program and if the latter, what GUI library are you using?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have a look at [java.util.Formatter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).

String.format() provides a convenient wrapper.

For example (modified from an example on the link):

```
   String s = String.format("e = %+10.4f", Math.E);
```

It goes beyond C's ?printf formats. For example, it supports an optional locale, and format symbols can be associated with an argument by explicit index rather than implicit.

**Edit:** Fixed the link above.

Answer (score 4):

`String.format(..)` and possibly `java.text.*`

Answer (score 2):

There's the Formatter class and its variants: String.format, PrintStream.printf.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach is to use printf() which works much the same as printf() in C.

```
double pi = Math.PI;
System.out.printf ("pi = %5.3f%n", pi);
```