# How to print with replacement in java?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java output formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417856/java-output-formatting)

Is there a way to print with replacement in Java, as you can do
in c++ where ("Number %d", 5) is for printing "Number 5".

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Yes, use `System.out.printf`. There are some slight differences from the C version.

- [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)
- [Format Specifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)

And your example literally translates to:

```
System.out.printf("Number %d", 5);
```

Answer (score 2):

Have your string to contain `%s` and then use the `String.format` method. Each parameter will be replaced in order of appeareance in the string.

Example:

```
String base = "This %s a %s";
String yourString = String.format(base, "is", "String");
```

In `yourString` the `%s` occurences are replaced by "is" first, then by "String". The result is `This is a String`;

*Edit:* As MouseEvent correctly pointed out, your question is related to numbers. For numbers, use `%d` in your string insterad and numeric parameters:

```
String base = "This %d a seven";
String yourString = String.format(base, 7);
```

Comment: `%d` will work for  numbers.